# Stop executing cron job on specific condition

Tags: php, mysql, shell, cron

I have a DB with 2 tables:

```
subscribers:
 _____________________________
|  id    |  name  |   email   |
|________|________|___________|
|  1     |  John  |   e@m.com |
|  ..    |   ..   |     ..    |
|  5000  |  Mark  |   c@b.com |
|________|________|___________|
```

```
last_id:
 _______
|  id   |
|_______|
| NULL  |
|_______|
```

Every day I run a cron job to send all the emails at once, But **The script is timing out after 100 sec**.

So instead I'm thinking of sending about 200 emails per time:

```
/* Get the id from last time is script was executed */
$last_id = "SELECT `id` FROM `last_id`";

/* Select the next 200 subscribers starting from the last id */
$query= "SELECT * FROM `subscribers` WHERE `id` > ". $last_id . " LIMIT 200";

/* Send 200 emails */
..

/* Get the last id of these 200 subscribers */
$last = ;

/* Update the value of `id` in `last_id` table */
$query= "UPDATE `last_id` SET `id` = ". $last;
```

The cron job runs this script every 10 minutes, But after sending all the emails the script would be executed over and over without sending any emails.

So how to stop executing this cron job after all the emails are sent, When `last_id` = `5000` and start it again the next day?

Comment: You can "build" the 10 minute pause into your php script directly: run it once per day, with a loop sending 200 mails each iteration, then waiting 10min. Alternatively, you could check if the end of the table is reached and put a status somewhere in database (last_id = -1 for example) and then have another cron reset it to 0 every day

Comment: By 10 minute pause, You mean using `sleep(600)`?

Comment: Yes, you can also perhaps `unset()` the memory consuming variables before `sleep()`, and once you reach the end of the table, you can reset `last_id` to 0 for the next day

Comment: *"So how to stop executing this cron job after all the emails are sent and start it again the next day?"*  What are you trying the optimize here? Don't wast hours thinking/programming optimizing a cronjob with a empty table select which is lighting fast to begin with.. The hours thinking/programming are not justifing a performance gain of **possibly** a few milliseconds.   The script might can use a `return` or `exit(0)` when PHP sees when the table is empty..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, So what do you suggest as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

We had an exercise like this at school once, we sorted it by adding a 'send date' column to the subscriber table. You select with a limit X and a date < then 'now', upon sending you update the records of these subscribers with the 'now' date.

The query wont select anything if all are send. so the cron will run but doesn't do anything.

And the next day, it will start with again as the select will return the 'unsend' records.

And if you don't want to use the dates, you can use a bool or tinyint, select where 'send' is 0 and set them to 1 after sending. And have another cron update all the records back to 0 run once daily/or whatever increment you want to send these emails.

Comment: Was the cron job executed every x minutes or every day?

Comment: Every X minutes.